# Crear una partición en PostgreSQL usando el conector JDBC de spark

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, spark

Necesito automatizar la creación de una partición en PostgreSQL pero utilizando un job de spark.

Si corro la siguiente consulta en la consola de postgresql, jala bien:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi_particion
PARTITION OF mi_tabla
FOR VALUES FROM ('<fecha1>') TO ('<fecha2>');
```

Pero cuando la intento meter dentro de una query en un job de spark de la siguiente manera:

```scala
var CreatePartitionTemplate=
  s"""
    |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mitabla_miparticion
    |PARTITION OF mi_tabla
    |FOR VALUES FROM ('%s') TO ('%s')
    |""".stripMargin
val createNewPartition = CreatePartitionTemplate.format(today, tomorrow)

spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", JdbcUrl)
  .option("user", PgUser)
  .option("password", PgPass)
  .option("query", createNewPartition)
  .load()
```

Me aparece el error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"

Comment: ¿Y si más bien le pones pg_partman a ese postgresql y así Spark no se mete con eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de overkillear y usar spark, mejor le hice caso a ChatGPT, y usé el conector jdbc de java pero en scala:

```scala
import java.sql.DriverManager

val CreateNewPartitionTemplate =
s"""
   |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_%s
   |PARTITION OF my_table
   |FOR VALUES FROM ('%s') TO ('%s')
   |""".stripMargin
/*Create new partition*/
val todayDateFormatted = todayDate.toString.replaceAll("-", "_")
val createNewPartitionSql = CreateNewPartitionTemplate.format(todayDateFormatted, todayDate, tomorrowDate)
println(createNewPartitionSql)

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, PgUser, PgPass)
val statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.executeUpdate(createNewPartitionSql)
connection.close()
```